# Java DropDown Menu Value Selection

Tags: java

I have a drop down menu in java with 3 options and right next to it a run button.
I am using eclipse in java and using apache wicket and html to run the program in a web browser. my question is, if i choose print data from the drop down and click on the run button it should print printing successful in the console. i have tried various methods, and its compiling but just not showing me the message that it should do according to the system.out.println statement.

```
    Button b = new Button("Ausführen");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(role.getValue().equals("Print Data")) {
          System.out.println("Printing successfull!");
        }
      }

    });

    form.add(b);
```

any ideas why?

Comment: what kind of object is form?
is the onSubmit method called at all, or just the if condition is not satisfied? What kind of Button is that?

Comment: form is the interface where i have added the objects (buttons, dropdown) onto. what do you mean by whether the onSubmit button is called at all? do i have to call it elsewhere as well?

Comment: generally, how would you write that IF the value of the selected dropdown item is equal to xyz, then do xyz.

Comment: You don't call the method in this snippet. You only provide an implementation via the anonymous class. That is why I ask if you really call it somewhere (via listener, or some other way).

Is this a java.awt.Button or something else?

Comment: yeh they are java.awt.button - could you please explain how i should change my code then. i am a beginner and i am slightly lost now

Comment: @peshkira could you please advise?

Comment: Priya , I havent worked much on apache wicket , but I can say this should be easy to debug - first , try sys out outside the if condition - if you see that printed - that means the if condition is evaluating to be false - may be the `String` value selected is not exactly "Print Data" - try `trim()`ming the string value from `role`. If you dont see the outside print as well , that means your `actionPerformed()` handler is not getting invoked. I would check if the button that is clicked is indeed the same button to which you are attaching the `actionListener`. Just some steps to debug. HTH.

Comment: Hi @Bhaskar, I am not using JButtons, just normal Form Buttons along with Wicket and HTML. but the actual code/function i am writing in Java. I have written this code:   

    System.out.println(role.getValue());
    if(role.getValue().equals("Print Data")) {

But When I invoke the function, it doesnt print the actual string from the drop down, but rather numbers e.g. the position. for example if my first option is selected then 0, for second 1 and so on and so forth. Any idea why this is doing it

Comment: OK - that means your handler is getting invoked indeed , a good thing to start with! It is printing the number because you are calling `role.getValue()` - "value" ought to be some number ( the ordinal , as with most gui drop downs ). Look for some method on `role` that says `getText()` or something similar - am not sure whats the API name.

Comment: @Bhaskar, I have tried doing that, but i can not find anything such as getText only getValue, getString(key) but they dont work either. There are others, but they dont make sense for me. Have you got an idea, what I could do? Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `role` ? Is it a swing/awt dropdown ? Show me its fully qualified classname / variable declaration.

Comment: private DropDownChoice<String> role = new DropDownChoice<String>(
   "RoleDropDown", new PropertyModel<String>(this, ""), readXML());

Comment: Priya , you need to define the handler `protected void onSelectionChanged(final Object newSelection) `. This method will be called whenever user selects an item from the drop down. You can then capture this value as you like and use it. Assuming you are new to Wicket ( as am I ) . suggest read this : https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html

Comment: where does this: protected void onSelectionChanged(final Object newSelection) go ? i guess this is a function, and if so, what do i write inside the function? thanks for your help bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionListener is not going to work with Apache Wicket I guess. Just use a normal Form Button, then create a seperate Print Class and write a print method in your onSubmit method.